# pyqtgraph : compute angle in viewbox from data points

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to orient a text item with the appropriate angle from the first 2 points of a curve, basically using the ratio of y-values and x-values to compute the angle of the line. The goal in the end is to align the texts with the curves, kinda like an abacus.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

# plot widget
pw = pg.plot(title="How to align the text item with the curves ?", pen="b")


def abacus(
        pw,         # a plot widget item
        x, ys,      # same x for all ys curves
        labels,     # text to display on each curve
        indx_txt=0, # index used to compute text angle and position
        width=2, color=(140, 140, 140, 140), fontsize=12
    ):
    
    # to store and return created items
    lines = []
    
    for y, lab in zip(ys, labels):
        line = pw.plot(
            x, y,
            pen=pg.mkPen(color=color, width=width, style=QtCore.Qt.DashLine),
            width=width, 
            name=lab, 
        )
        
        # first try : doesn't work cause the viewbox scale doesn't 
        # follow data scale
        xs, ys = line.getData()
        ratio = (ys[indx_txt+1]-ys[indx_txt])/(xs[indx_txt+1]-xs[indx_txt])
        angle = np.arctan(ratio)
        
        txt = pg.TextItem(
            text=lab,
            color=color, 
            anchor=(0, 0.9),
            border=None, 
            angle=angle,     # angle is here
        )
        
        font = QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(fontsize)
        txt.setFont(font)
        pw.addItem(txt)
        txt.setPos(x[indx_txt], y[indx_txt])
        lines.append((line, txt))
    return lines
        
        
# create dummy data and labels
x = np.arange(5, 8)
ys = 2*(3*(x+3)+np.outer(x, x))
labs = [f"This is the {i} curve" for i in range(3)]
    
lines = abacus(pw, x, ys, labs)

pg.exec()
```

I tried using the data `line.getData()` to compute the angle, but the data scales do not follow the viewbox scale so I don't get the appropriate angle.

[image: Example with wrong angle, text are not aligned with curves]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewBox` provides the signal `sigRangeChanged`, which emits every time the `ViewBox`'s range changes due to resizing, pans, zooms, etc.  You can leverage this feature along with the method `ViewBox.mapFromView` to achieve the result you're looking for. You get a bonus with this approach: the text angle will adjust dynamically even when the aspect ratio of the view box changes due to resizing of the widget and/or scale adjustments of either axis.

The angle calculation function is similar to that provided by @mugiseyebrows, but uses the information from the view instead of the axes:

```py
def calc_angle(line, idx=0):
    x, y = line.getData()
    p1 = line.getViewBox().mapFromView(QtCore.QPointF(float(x[idx]), float(y[idx])))
    p2 = line.getViewBox().mapFromView(QtCore.QPointF(float(x[idx + 1]), float(y[idx + 1])))
    dx = p2.x() - p1.x()
    dy = p2.y() - p1.y()
    angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(-dy, dx))
    return angle
```

The event handler for `sigRangeChanged` calculates the angle of each line in pixel space and sets the text angle:

```py
def on_vb_range_changed(vb, rng, changed):
    global ABACUS_LINES, TXT_IDX
    for line, txt in ABACUS_LINES:
        txt.setAngle(calc_angle(line, TXT_IDX))
```

Note the renamed `ABACUS_LINES` and `TXT_IDX` variables.  I renamed them to alleviate potential reader confusion with the variables inside `abacus()`. They are now used by your main calling code as follows:

```py
TXT_IDX = 0 # adjust as needed
ABACUS_LINES = abacus(pw, x, ys, labs, TXT_IDX)
pw.getViewBox().sigRangeChanged.connect(on_vb_range_changed)
```

(Also note that you can avoid using globals if you consolidate all of your code into a class, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.)

Here, the signal connection is made **after** creating the abacus plot to reduce the number of handler calls.  During construction of the plot, the view box adjusts many times as plot items are added to it, and we want to be on the tail end of those changes.  In your example the viewbox changes its range 12 times until its layout is complete.  Subscribing to the event after drawing the plots reduces the handler calls to just two.

As I mentioned in the beginning, the nice bonus of this approach is that the text stays aligned with the lines even when the aspect ratio of the view box changes.  This is because the text angle is recalculated every time the connected event is emitted.

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

# plot widget
pw = pg.plot(title="How to align the text item with the curves ?", pen="b")


def calc_angle(line, idx=0):
    x, y = line.getData()
    p1 = line.getViewBox().mapFromView(QtCore.QPointF(float(x[idx]), float(y[idx])))
    p2 = line.getViewBox().mapFromView(QtCore.QPointF(float(x[idx + 1]), float(y[idx + 1])))
    dx = p2.x() - p1.x()
    dy = p2.y() - p1.y()
    angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(-dy, dx))
    return angle


def on_vb_range_changed(vb, rng, changed):
    global ABACUS_LINES, TXT_IDX
    for line, txt in ABACUS_LINES:
        txt.setAngle(calc_angle(line, TXT_IDX))


def abacus(
    pw,         # a plot widget item
    x, ys,      # same x for all ys curves
    labels,     # text to display on each curve
    indx_txt=0,  # index used to compute text angle and position
    width=2, color=(140, 140, 140, 140), fontsize=12
):

    # to store and return created items
    lines = []

    for y, lab in zip(ys, labels):
        line = pw.plot(
            x, y,
            pen=pg.mkPen(color=color, width=width, style=QtCore.Qt.DashLine),
            width=width,
            name=lab,
        )

        txt = pg.TextItem(
            text=lab,
            color=color,
            anchor=(0, 0.9),
            border=None,
        )

        font = QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(fontsize)
        txt.setFont(font)
        pw.addItem(txt)
        txt.setPos(x[indx_txt], y[indx_txt])
        lines.append((line, txt))
    return lines


# create dummy data and labels
x = np.arange(5, 8)
ys = 2*(3*(x+3)+np.outer(x, x))
labs = [f"This is the {i} curve" for i in range(3)]

TXT_IDX = 0 # adjust as needed
ABACUS_LINES = abacus(pw, x, ys, labs, TXT_IDX)
pw.getViewBox().sigRangeChanged.connect(on_vb_range_changed)

pg.exec()
```

Comment: This works well, the next step was to keep the text aligned but your solution already implements this which is exactly what I wanted. +1 for registering the signal after all lines are created.

Comment: I ended up creating a cleaner class and full example [here](https://gist.github.com/mocquin/b5c40d37686283c39884589c24aa3791).

Comment: Excellent.  Line 24 needs to be something like `self.sp = sp = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QSpinBox()` or you'll get `AttributeError` a few lines later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain pixel coordinates of data points somehow, for example you can extract mapping algorithm from `pyqtgraph\graphicsItems\AxisItem.py`, it uses two variables to map units to pixels: `xScale` and `offset` which is calculated from geometry and value range.

```py
class AxisHelper:
    def __init__(self, axisItem):
        if axisItem.orientation == 'left':
            axis = 0
        else:
            axis = 1
        bounds = axisItem.mapRectFromParent(axisItem.geometry())
        dif = axisItem.range[1] - axisItem.range[0]
        if axis == 0:
            xScale = -bounds.height() / dif
            offset = axisItem.range[0] * xScale - bounds.height()
        else:
            xScale = bounds.width() / dif
            offset = axisItem.range[0] * xScale
        self._xScale = xScale
        self._offset = offset

    def map(self, v):
        return (v * self._xScale) - self._offset
```

Then you can use it to obtain pixel coordinates and calculate angle. Notice that trigonometric functions returns angles in radians, but `TextItem` expects angle in degrees, so you need to convert it. Notice that pixel coordinates go from top to bottom, but units go bottom to top so you need to flip sign or use `y1 - y2` instead of `y2 - y1`.

```py
def set_angle(pw, txt, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    left = AxisHelper(pw.getAxis('left'))
    bottom = AxisHelper(pw.getAxis('bottom'))
    x1p = bottom.map(x1)
    x2p = bottom.map(x2)
    y1p = left.map(y1)
    y2p = left.map(y2)
    angle = np.arctan((y1p - y2p) / (x2p - x1p)) / np.pi * 180
    txt.setAngle(angle)
```

And for some reason you need to call this function after scaling and calculating occurs, or angles will be slightly incorrect. You can use single shot timer for that. Zero timer doesn't work for some reason, 100ms timer seems to work. For binding values to function you can use `functools.partial` or lambda with optional args.

```py
        txt = pg.TextItem(
            text=lab,
            color=color, 
            anchor=(0, 1),
            border=None
        )
        xs, ys = line.getData()
        x2, x1 = xs[indx_txt+1], xs[indx_txt]
        y2, y1 = ys[indx_txt+1], ys[indx_txt]
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, partial(set_angle, pw, txt, x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

Complete code:

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from functools import partial

# plot widget
pw = pg.plot(title="How to align the text item with the curves ?", pen="b")

class AxisHelper:
    def __init__(self, axisItem):
        if axisItem.orientation == 'left':
            axis = 0
        else:
            axis = 1
        bounds = axisItem.mapRectFromParent(axisItem.geometry())
        dif = axisItem.range[1] - axisItem.range[0]
        if axis == 0:
            xScale = -bounds.height() / dif
            offset = axisItem.range[0] * xScale - bounds.height()
        else:
            xScale = bounds.width() / dif
            offset = axisItem.range[0] * xScale
        self._xScale = xScale
        self._offset = offset

    def map(self, v):
        return (v * self._xScale) - self._offset

def set_angle(pw, txt, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    left = AxisHelper(pw.getAxis('left'))
    bottom = AxisHelper(pw.getAxis('bottom'))
    x1p = bottom.map(x1)
    x2p = bottom.map(x2)
    y1p = left.map(y1)
    y2p = left.map(y2)
    angle = np.arctan((y1p - y2p) / (x2p - x1p)) / np.pi * 180
    txt.setAngle(angle)

def abacus(
        pw,         # a plot widget item
        x, ys,      # same x for all ys curves
        labels,     # text to display on each curve
        indx_txt=0, # index used to compute text angle and position
        width=2, color=(140, 140, 140, 140), fontsize=12
    ):
    
    # to store and return created items
    lines = []

    for y, lab in zip(ys, labels):
        line = pw.plot(
            x, y,
            pen=pg.mkPen(color=color, width=width, style=QtCore.Qt.DashLine),
            width=width, 
            name=lab, 
        )
        
        txt = pg.TextItem(
            text=lab,
            color=color, 
            anchor=(0, 1),
            border=None
        )
        xs, ys = line.getData()
        x2, x1 = xs[indx_txt+1], xs[indx_txt]
        y2, y1 = ys[indx_txt+1], ys[indx_txt]
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, partial(set_angle, pw, txt, x1, y1, x2, y2))

        font = QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(fontsize)
        txt.setFont(font)
        pw.addItem(txt)
        txt.setPos(x[indx_txt], y[indx_txt])
        lines.append((line, txt))
        
    return lines
        
# create dummy data and labels
x = np.arange(5, 8)
ys = 2*(3*(x+3)+np.outer(x, x))
labs = [f"This is the {i} curve" for i in range(3)]

lines = abacus(pw, x, ys, labs)

pg.exec()
```